# Addition of chars adding one character in front

Tags: python, algorithm

what I'm trying to implement is a function that increments a string by one character, for example:

```
'AAA' + 1 = 'AAB'
'AAZ' + 1 = 'ABA'
'ZZZ' + 1 = 'AAAA'
```

I've implemented function for the first two cases, however I can't think of any solution for the third case.

Here's my code :

```
def new_sku(s):
    s = s[::-1]
    already_added = False
    new_sku = str()

    for i in s:
        if not already_added:
            if (i < 'Z'):
                already_added = True
            new_sku += chr((ord(i)+1)%65%26 + 65)
        else:
            new_sku += i

    return new_sku[::-1]
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Will your `s` be always words with capital letters?

Comment: You are basically implementing base 26 addition, you'll need to consider how carrying works when one of your 'digits' becomes greater that 26.  The python `divmod` method will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about ?

```
def new_sku(s):
    s = s[::-1]
    already_added = False
    new_sku = str()

    for i in s:
        if not already_added:
            if (i < 'Z'):
                already_added = True
            new_sku += chr((ord(i)+1)%65%26 + 65)
        else:
            new_sku += i

    if not already_added: # carry still left?
        new_sku += 'A'

    return new_sku[::-1]
```

Sample run :-

```
$ python sku.py Z
AA
$ python sku.py ZZZ
AAAA
$ python sku.py AAA
AAB
$ python sku.py AAZ
ABA
```

Comment: Only one suggestion - declare magic number `65` as a "const", best way would be to explicitly show that it's an `ord('A')`

Answer (score 9):

If you're dealing with [bijective numeration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijective_numeration#The_bijective_base-26_system), then you probably have (or should have) functions to convert to/from bijective representation anyway; it'll be a lot easier just to convert to an integer, increment it, then convert back:

```
def from_bijective(s, digits=string.ascii_uppercase):
    return sum(len(digits) ** i * (digits.index(c) + 1)
               for i, c in enumerate(reversed(s)))

def to_bijective(n, digits=string.ascii_uppercase):
    result = []
    while n > 0:
        n, mod = divmod(n - 1, len(digits))
        result += digits[mod]
    return ''.join(reversed(result))

def new_sku(s):
    return to_bijective(from_bijective(s) + 1)
```

Comment: Superb. Wish I had thought of it.

Answer (score 3):

You have to think of 'AAA', 'ZZZ', ... as representation of the value you manipulate.

First, parse the value:

```
val = sum(pow(26, i) * (ord(v) - ord('A') + 1) for i, v in enumerate(value[::-1]))
```

Then, add value to it:

```
val = val + 1
```

### Edit

The final value is given by:

```
res = ""
while val > 0:
     val, n = divmod(val - 1, 26)
     res = chr(n+ord('A')) + res
```

The lack of representation for zero requires the value passed to divmod to be decremented at each turn, which i have not found a way of doing with a list comprehension.

### Edit

Rather than `ord()` and `chr()`, it is possible to use `string.ascii_uppercase.index()` and `string.ascii_uppercase[]`

Comment: nice one, very clever

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary : thanks, I misplaced the -1 in the last line

Comment: Yes, for some reason the fact that there is no letter for representing 0 is a problem (which is implied by AAA+1 = AAB)

Comment: Time to get the [disciplined](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/37/disciplined) badge then or may be you can fix it.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of some recursion here:

```
def new_sku(s):
    s = s[::-1]
    new_s = ''
    return expand(s.upper(), new_s)[::-1]

import string
chars = string.ascii_uppercase

def expand(s, new_s, carry_forward=True):

    if not s:
        new_s += 'A' if carry_forward else ''
        return new_s

    new_s += chars[(ord(s[0]) - ord('A') + carry_forward) % 26]

    # Slice the first character, and expand rest of the string
    if s[0] == 'Z': 
        return expand(s[1:], new_s, carry_forward)
    else:
        return expand(s[1:], new_s, False)


print new_sku('AAB')
print new_sku('AAZ')
print new_sku('ZZZ')
print new_sku('aab')
print new_sku('aaz')
print new_sku('zzz')
```

Output:

```
AAC
ABA
AAAA
AAC
ABA
AAAA
```

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary. Working towards shortening it now.

Answer (score 1):

I would implement this like a base-26 addition with carry.

So start from the right of the string, add 1. If it reaches Z, wrap to A and bump the next left most character up one. If the left most character reaches Z, add an A to the left of the string.

```
s = ["Z","Z","Z"]
done = 0

index = len(s) - 1
while done == 0:
    if s[index] < "Z":
        s[index] = chr(ord(s[index]) + 1)
        done = 1
    else:
        s[index] = "A"
        if index == 0:
            s = ["A"] + s
            done = 1
        else:
            index = index - 1

print s
```

Answer (score 1):

Just check if the string is all `Z`s, and if it is, replace it by a string with length `len(s) + 1`, consisting of just `A`s:

```
if s == "Z" * len(s):
    return "A" * (len(s) + 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
alp='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZA'
def rec(s):
    if len(s)==0:return 'A'
    last_letter=s[-1]
    if last_letter=='Z':return rec(s[:-1])+'A'
    return s[:-1]+alp[(alp.find(last_letter)+1)]
```

result

```
>>> rec('AAA')
'AAB'
>>> rec('AAZ')
'ABA'
>>> rec('ZZZ')
'AAAA'
>>> rec('AZA')
'AZB'
```

Comment: @njzk2 what do you expect for `aza`?? `is it azb`??

Comment: @njzk2 hay i updated my code with recurssion now it works fine. :-))

Comment: @njzk2 if you want to make it working with lower case letters just use `.upper()` ie `rec(s.upper())`

Comment: @njzk2 it is not fair to gave me downvote. even i updated the answer in a corrected way.

Comment: @njzk2 sorry :-)) i got upvotes now.. anyway did you solve your problem. what abut my recurrsion solution??

Answer (score 1):

How about this? As a simple way to handle the string getting longer you can prepend a leading '@' and strip it if it wasn't incremented:

```
>>> def new_sku(s):
    def increment(s):
        if s.endswith('Z'):
            return increment(s[:-1])+'A'
        else:
            return s[:-1]+chr(ord(s[-1])+1)
    t = increment('@'+s)
    return t.lstrip('@')

>>> new_sku('AAA')
'AAB'
>>> new_sku('AAZ')
'ABA'
>>> new_sku('ZZZ')
'AAAA'
```

If the recursion worries you then you can flatten it the way you already did but still use the '@' character added and stripped.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for-else` loop:

```
from string import ascii_uppercase as au

def solve(strs):
    lis = []
    for i, c in enumerate(strs[::-1], 1):
        ind = au.index(c) + 2
        lis.append(au[(ind%26)-1])
        if ind <= 26:
            break
    else:
        # This will execute only if the for-loop didn't break.
        lis.append('A')

    return strs[:-1*i] + "".join(lis[::-1])

print solve('AAA')
print solve('AAZ')
print solve('ZZZ')
print solve('AZZZ')
print solve('ZYZZ')
print solve('ZYYZZ')
```

**output:**

```
AAB
ABA
AAAA
BAAA
ZZAA
ZYZAA
```

Answer (score 0):

We can see there are 3 conditions totally, you can iterate the string and process one of the conditions. 
You can use the string.ascii_uppercase instead of chr and ord

```
import string
def add(s):
    s = list(s)[::-1]
    for index, char in enumerate(s):
        if char != "Z":
            s[index] = string.ascii_uppercase[string.ascii_uppercase.index(char) + 1]
            return s[::-1]
        elif char == "Z" and (index != len(s) - 1):
            s[index] = "A"
        elif char == "Z" and (index == len(s) - 1):
            s[index] = "A"
            return ["A"] + s[::-1]
```